# Text Substitution Using Python Dictionary in re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I have an input file in the below format:

```
<ftnt>
<p><su>1</su> aaaaaaaaaaa </p>
</ftnt>
...........
...........
...........
... the <su>1</su> is availabe in the .........
```

I need to convert this to the below format by replacing the value and deleting the whole data in `ftnt` tags:

```
"""...
...
... the aaaaaaaaaaa is available in the ..........."""
```

Please find the code which i have written. Initially i saved the keys & values in dictionary and tried to replace the value based on the key using grouping.

```
import re
dict = {}
in_file = open("in.txt", "r")
outfile = open("out.txt", "w")
File1 = in_file.read()

infile1 = File1.replace("\n", " ")
for mo in re.finditer(r'<p><su>(\d+)</su>(.*?)</p>',infile1):

     dict[mo.group(1)] = mo.group(2)

subval = re.sub(r'<p><su>(\d+)</su>(.*?)</p>','',infile1)
subval = re.sub('<su>(\d+)</su>',dict[\\1], subval)

outfile.write(subval)
```

I tried to use dictionary in `re.sub` but I am getting a `KeyError`. I don't know why this happens could you please tell me how to use. I'd appreciate any help here.

Comment: Use four spaces when formatting code in your question. It's much more legible and doesn't leave spaces in between pieces of code

Comment: I edited the formatting, please correct if something looks wrong (use the [edit] link under the question).

Comment: [Not again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)...

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `lambda` for the second argument to `re.sub`, rather than a string with backreferences:

```
subval = re.sub('<su>(\d+)</su>',lambda m:dict[m.group(1)], subval)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't name dictionaries `dict` or you'll destroy the `dict` function.  Second, `\\1` doesn't work outside of a string hence the syntax error.  I think the best bet is to take advantage of [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
import re

# store the substitutions
subs = {}

# read the data
in_file = open("in.txt", "r")
contents = in_file.read().replace("\n", " ")
in_file.close()

# save some regexes for later
ftnt_tag = re.compile(r'<ftnt>.*</ftnt>')
var_tag = re.compile(r'<p><su>(\d+)</su>(.*?)</p>')

# pull the ftnt tag out
ftnt = ftnt_tag.findall(contents)[0]
contents = ftnt_tag.sub('', contents)

# pull the su
for match in var_tag.finditer(ftnt):
    # added s so they aren't numbers, useful for format
    subs["s" + match.group(1)] = match.group(2)

# replace <su>1</su> with {s1}
contents = re.sub(r"<su>(\d+)</su>", r"{s\1}", contents)

# now that the <su> are the keys, we can just use str.format
out_file = open("out.txt", "w")
out_file.write( contents.format(**subs) )
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was of great help to me.